# JCR: Jackrabbit OCM - binary data and lazy loading

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

my goal is to store information about projects within Jackrabbit. Each project can consist out of several sub-projects with project related files/documents attached to them.

Consider the following structure:

```
-project 1
 -project 1.1
 -project 1.2
  -project 1.2.1
  -project 1.2.2
-project 2
```

I have a java class representing each project which looks like this:

```
public class Project {

  @Field
  private String name;

  @Collection
  private List<Project> subprojects;

  // more properties + getter/setter
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there anything similar to lazy loading from ORM tools? For example: When I want to get the information about `project 1` I don't need all the information from subprojects. Whats the best way to achive this?
- Whats the best way to attach binary data (files, documents, images) to a project when using OCM?

(Unfortunately the Jackrabbit OCM documentation is not really detailed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lazy loading, you can achieve this by specifying `proxy=true` in Bean or Collection annotation.

Binary data can be represented as `jcr:data` property of `nt:resource` so the mapping looks something like this.

```
@Node(jcrType = "nt:resource")
public class ResourceModel extends MimeTypeModel {

    @Field(path = true)
    String path = null;

    @Field(jcrName = "jcr:data")
    java.io.InputStream jcr_data = null;
}
```

It is true the document of OCM is not updated, but you can find the useful information from `/org/apache/jackrabbit/ocm/config/jackrabbit-ocm-1.5.dtd` under `src/main/resources` in the source distribution.

HTH,